# In which scenario UDP datagrams can be reordered in a sender socket buffer?

Tags: sockets, networking, linux-kernel, udp

Successfull `sendto` system call assumes that data is placed into a socket buffer.

[Kernel documentation](https://docs.kernel.org/networking/timestamping.html) assumes that data stored in a socket buffer can somehow be reordered.

`Packets can be reordered in the transmit path, for instance in the packet scheduler.`

I cannot imagine when this can happen for a UDP socket. I was assuming that for a UDP socket its send buffer works as sort of a queue and data which is requested to be sent is never reordered.

So can you please explain how it can happen? Ideally I want to get some understanding to what extent this reordering can take place.

P.S. I am interested in sender side only. Because packets sent can be rerouted to MSG_ERRQUEUE using timestamping feature.  I understand that nothing is guaranteed on receiver side.

Comment: It could happen if a pool pf threads is running the various protocol levels.  IME it's a bad example, 'for instance, by taking different routes'  would have been better.

Comment: I think your interpretation is wrong. The cited phrase says nothing about reordering of packets in the socket buffer, but only about "transmit path, for instance the packet scheduler". But in general it does not actually matter where the reordering might happen, the important thing is that it can happen (and also packet loss and packet duplication) and that the recipient must take this into account when receiving the packets.

Comment: What it means is that the sockets can be received in any order by the endpoint, as each individual packet could be slowed down or dropped. Packets should still be sent in the correct order from your machine.

Comment: I suspect the author of the kernel documentation had something like QOS packet scheduling in mind:  https://www.softprayog.in/tutorials/network-traffic-control-with-tc-command-in-linux  "3.2 SCHEDULING

Scheduling is deciding which packet would be transmitted next. This is done by rearranging the packets in the queue. The objectives are to provide a quick response for interactive applications and also to provide adequate bandwidth for bulk transfers like downloads initiated by remote hosts. Scheduling is done at egress." (dunno if this type of scheduling can happen within a given socket tho)

Comment: The transit path can actually have multiple paths, some of which may be slower than others, leading to out-of-order delivery. You will also find the packets get dropped all the time in the transit path, leading to missing packets. TCP takes care of resending lost segments, but UDP has no such facility.

Comment: I suspect it could happen when you have a multi-core computer, a multi-queue network card and the packets are transmitted from different cores

Comment: "Packets should still be sent in the correct order from your machine" - that's exactly the question. I still have doubts.
"I suspect the author of the kernel documentation had something like QOS packet scheduling in mind" - interesting. I don't know if QOS can be somehow aplied within a single UDP socket, e.g. different packets have different QOS. Sockets API does not have anything like that.
" multi-queue network card" - never heard of it. Just googled and still need to read more. Good hint.

Comment: I also came to an idea that if we have a UDP socket which is not binded to anything, then sending via this socket to different endpoints can result in using different NICs, and if one NIC is still busy then another one can be served instead. But I need to read kernel sources more thoroughly